# Use an index in a SELECT statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I created an index called Z7 and I want to use it in a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WITH (INDEX(Z7)) WHERE First_Name NOT LIKE ('J%');
```

But it shows me this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Trust the optimizer.

Comment: `LIKE` is not a function, it's a _predicate_. I.e. you can skip those extra parentheses and simply write `WHERE First_Name NOT LIKE 'J%'` to make code clearer.

Comment: I know that, I just added them because I thought that ' next to the ; was causing the error

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm#i8327

Comment: "you might know that a certain index is more selective for certain queries" - even without the WHERE part it shows the same error

Comment: Use correct syntax. Oracle does not recognise `WITH (INDEX(Z7)) ` in the  [table_reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6)

Comment: What's the correct syntax then @MarmiteBomber ?

Comment: @Mina - see my answer below - use the INDEX hint: `SELECT /*+ index(Employees Z7) */ * FROM Employees WHERE ...`

Comment: Ok thank you so much, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the `LIKE` predicate that can be resolved with a *index range scan* there is no index access path in Oracle that would implement a `NOT LIKE` that would need to do two range scans *before* and *after* your LIKE value.

Let's illustrate it in this setup with a table that has only one row satisfying your not like predicate.

```
create table Employees as
select 'J'||rownum as First_Name, lpad('x',1000,'y') pad from dual connect by level <= 10000
union all 
select 'Xname', 'zzzzz' from dual;

create index Z7 on Employees (First_Name);
```

The query

```
SELECT * FROM Employees  WHERE First_Name NOT LIKE ('J%');
```

performs as expected a `FULL TABLE SCAN`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |           |    37 | 37259 |   398   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEES |    37 | 37259 |   398   (1)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("FIRST_NAME" NOT LIKE 'J%')
```

You may [*hint*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-EC0D9F8A-20E7-4281-A16A-6B9C993F2930) Oracle to use index as follows (note that your syntax `FROM Employees WITH (INDEX(Z7)) WHERE` is wrong and causing your error!)

```
SELECT /*+ index(Employees Z7) */ * FROM Employees  WHERE First_Name NOT LIKE ('J%');
```

This will indeed cause the index usage, but not in the sence you probablly intended.

If you examines the execution plan you'll see the `INDEX FULL SCAN`, that means, Oracle walks through the *complete index* from `A` to `Z`, filter the entires in the index that are `not like` your predicates (see the `FILTER` in the plan below) and for the selected keys access the table.

So generally you'll be not happy with this plan for a *large index* as it will take substantially longer that the full table scan.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |           |  9433 |  9276K|  2912   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| EMPLOYEES |  9433 |  9276K|  2912   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN                   | Z7        |  9433 |       |    25   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("FIRST_NAME" NOT LIKE 'J%')
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) how to produce the *execution plan* for the query